# Importing file contents directly into database - Excel spreadsheet needing repair

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I am working on a project where I am storing files directly within a MySQL Database. The code is working perfectly fine, storing and downloading text files, pictures and PDF, but when using Excel spreadsheets it has a problem.

If I store an Excel spread (.xlsx) file, the upload works fine, but when I download the file, the download seems to work fine, but when I open the spreadsheet I get the following:

`We found a problem with some content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbench, click Yes?'`

When I press `Yes` I then get the following:

`Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.`

When doing this, Excel loads up fine and everything looks OK, but why would I be getting this error, and why would it need to be repaired.

I am storing the file using the following:

```
private function writeFileToDatabase($fileName, $tmpName, $type, $fileSize, $fileArea, &$error)
        {
            $fileName = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileName);
            $fileSize = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileSize);
            $type = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $type);
            $fileArea = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileArea);

            //Open the uploaded file
            $fh = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
            if (!$fh)
            {
                $error = "Could not open uploaded file";
                return false;
            }
            $content = fread($fh, filesize($tmpName));
            $content = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $content);
            fclose($fh);

            //Store the file in the database
            $query = "INSERT INTO file_store (RecordID, Area, FileName, ContentType, Size, FileContent) "
                . "VALUES ('$this->recordID', '$fileArea', '$fileName', '$type', '$fileSize', '$content')";
            $result = $this->conn->query($query);
}
```

I download the file using the following:

```
function downloadFile($fileID)
        {
            $fileID = mysqli_escape_string($this->conn, $fileID);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM file_store WHERE id='$fileID'";
            $result = $this->conn->query($query);
            if ($result)
            {
                $data = $result->fetch_array();
                header("Content-length: " . $data["Size"]);
                header("Content-type: " . $data["ContentType"]);
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $data["FileName"]);
                echo $data["FileContent"];
            }
            else
            {
                echo mysqli_error($this->conn);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you open both excel files in a text editor, uploaded and downloaded, do you see anything in the file that is different. This would typically be something at the very beginning or very end and could be as simple as a whitespace. Also, how are you storing the files in the database (data type should be something binary like a blob)? And have you tried to prepare/bind your query? It might help with potential extra characters being added. Plus you don't need to escape and it is more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
echo $data["FileContent"];
```

Try Adding this:

```
ob_clean();
flush();
```

If that still doesn't work - maybe try trapping for content type and if it's not a text file add another header:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
```

Comment: As simple as that, just needed the ob_clean() and flush() to fix it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Boardy You could also capture that and write it to a file so you can see what the issue is and fix it. There is likely something like whitespace being output before.

Comment: Nice - it's a common issue with php and echo'ing lots of content.